# Numpy Python: Sorting columns of an array in alphabetical order

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, alphabetical

I'm currently working with Python 3 and Numpy. I have a structured array created by using `numpy.genfromtxt("textfile.txt", names=True)` and I want to sort the columns in alphabetical order.

- The first row contains the names of the columns.
- The other columns contain the accompanying values per instance.

I simply want to switch the order of the columns to the alphabetical order of the column names. 
For instance, now the order of the columns is `'year'`, `'population'`, `'area'` and I want it to become `'area', 'population', 'year'`.
Thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: Look into [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I haven't managed to use argsort to order alphabetically. Do I need to tune a parameter?

Comment: Abdou, I think you misunderstood the question. He does not want to sort the records in the array, he wants to reorder the columns.

Comment: @V.K. I just realized. Select the arrays by name and stack or concatenate them together in the order you want.

Comment: @Frederiquevdb, can you please provide a toy dataset to work with?

Comment: I just found a solution. It should be: x[numpy.sort(x.dtype.names)].

Comment: Please add it as an answer for future users looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following numpy array, the answer is:

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([(2015, 34, 12, 13), (2016, 41, 6, 7), (2016, 17, 5, 2),
       (2013, 21, 8, 19), (2013, 1, 81, 9)], 
      dtype=[('year', '<i8'), ('tigers', '<i8'), ('monkeys', '<i8'), ('cows', '<i8')])

x[numpy.sort(x.dtype.names)]

# Output:
array([(13, 12, 34, 2015), (7, 6, 41, 2016), (2, 5, 17, 2016),
       (19, 8, 21, 2013), (9, 81, 1, 2013)], 
      dtype=[('cows', '<i8'), ('monkeys', '<i8'), ('tigers', '<i8'), ('year', '<i8')])
```